# iOS detect bluetooth on/off without CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I want to find out if bluetooth is turned on/off on iOS without using CoreBluetooth (need to support iPad 2 etc.) or the private BluetoothManager framework (need to submit to app store).

I literally just need to know if bluetooth is on/off, nothing more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it without using Core Bluetooth Framework. Is there a particular reason why you dont want to use that framework ?

Comment: As I said I need to support iPad 2 and other devices that don't have BLE that CoreBluetooth is for.